# Как правильно настроить Spring data jpa с помощью java config

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Сам класс конфига

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "test", entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringJPA_Config {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");
        dataSource.setUsername("kosavpa");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("test.Person");

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {

        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Класс сущности

```
package test;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "second_name")
    private String secondName;
    @Column(name = "patronymic")
    private String patronymic;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private int phoneNumber;

    public Person(){}

    public Person(String firstName, String secondName, String patronymic, String email, int phoneNumber) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public Person(long id, String firstName, String secondName, String patronymic, String email, int phoneNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }

    public void setPatronymic(String patronymic) {
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getSecondName() {
        return secondName;
    }

    public String getPatronymic() {
        return patronymic;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public int getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Repository

```
package test;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface PersonRepo extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

Main

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import test.Person;
import test.PersonRepo;
import test.SpringJPA_Config;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringJPA_Config.class);

        PersonRepo repo = (PersonRepo) context.getBean("personRepo");
        Person spange = new Person("spange", "bob", "sqaowich", "sbs@list.ru", 654);
        repo.save(spange);
    }
}
```

Pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.22</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

При запуске main получаю ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepo' defined in test.PersonRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on SpringJPA_Config: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class test.Person
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:936)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class test.Person
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:583)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:233)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:182)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:165)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:325)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: @Savelly Покажи git репозиторий с этим проектом, если есть.

Comment: https://github.com/kosavpa/SpringDataJpaTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аннотировал интерфейс, наследующийся от CrudRepository, аннотацией @Repository.
Слегка подправил класс конфига:
сделал изменения в @EnableJpaRepositories, добавил @ComponentScan и изменил метод transactionManager()
Листинг конфига:

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"test"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(value = {"test"})
public class SpringJPA_Config {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");
        dataSource.setUsername("kosavpa");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("test");

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    }
}
```

Актуальный pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

После всех правок заработало.

Ссылка на github: https://github.com/kosavpa/SpringDataJpaTest